# VBA - Resize an Array according to a Value in a cell

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

In my excel worksheet, I have a string of numbers from B1 to B100 that are random. What i want to do but can't quite figure out is how to store them in an Array, and according to the value entered in A1 we'll call this 'n', to resize the array using ReDim to the size of 'n'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make sure you're not setting your array size upon declaration.

This works for example:

```
Dim arr() As Integer 'declare array but do not dimension it
Dim ws As Worksheet 'declare worksheet
Dim nsize As Integer 'size variable of cell A1
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'set worksheet variable
nsize = ws.Cells(1, 1).Value 'get cell A1 value
ReDim arr(nsize) 'redim array
```

Unless I've misunderstood something...

Hope this helps!

Comment: However, I think if you need to redim the array multiple times this might not work...
**Edit:** Nevermind... it seems to work if I loop and redim at different sizes

Comment: Also... if you wish to set values based on your range B1 to B100 and _then_ resize based on A1, you can use `ReDim Preserve` to do so

Comment: I've just tried to run this in a macro, but it doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you're using the first worksheet as the `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` line is assuming you're using the first worksheet. Additionally, make sure you're wrapping my code in a sub or function and then calling that function. Apart from that I've tested this with random A1 values and it's working...

Comment: How can it ReDim the array? There is no defined range for the array?

Comment: I'm not sure I can explain much further. ReDim is exactly for the purpose of setting the array to a specified dimension. In this case, I used "nsize" as my dimension. The array you ReDim does not need to have a range of values, you can simply ReDim the size.

Comment: `Sub List()
    Dim List(1 To 100, 1 To 1) As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 100
        List(i, 1) = Rnd(-i)
    Next i
    Range("B1:B100").Value = UnsortedList
    End Sub`
The Code above was to get a random set of values from B1:B100

Comment: `Sub Test2()
    Dim arr() As Integer 'declare array but do not dimension it
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'declare worksheet
    Dim nsize As Integer 'size variable of cell A1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'set worksheet variable
    nsize = ws.Cells(1, 1).Value 'get cell A1 value
    ReDim arr(nsize) 'redim array
    End Sub`
When i try and run this macro it does not ReDim the numbers from B1:B100 e.g. if A1 had the number 50, I want it to only show the first 50 numbers from B1 to B100, so it will only show B1 to B50

Comment: You're declaring your array with a size initially, which I warned against. It sounds like you want to _generate_ the list of random numbers in B1 to B100 in code then read the first n of them into your array.
In that case, ReDim your array as `ReDim arr(nsize,1)` and you'll get a two dimensional array based on the number set in A1. From that point you can loop through and get your random numbers. I cannot code this for you, you have the pieces, just put it together.
So, loop, generate randoms in B1:B100, then ReDim, then loop to read into array. In future please include your code first.